# Verification of stkokes theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Verify Stokes’ Theorem for $$v = (y − z + 2)\vec{i} + (yz + 4)\vec{j} − xz\vec{k}$$ where $S$ is the surface of the cube bounded by $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $z = 0$, $x = 2$, $y = 2$, $z = 2$ with the face in the $(x, y)$-plane (i.e. $z = 0$) missing.

Can anyone help me understand this?